# C# List ConvertAll with Index

Tags: c#, list, linq

Consider an input list, X, consisting of objects of type Tx, for which you need to run one of several functions, y_a = A(x), y_b = B(x), etc... (all of which output objects of Ty) to generate an output list, Y. Finally, the choice of conversion functions is a function of the index of the element within the list.

Ideally, the solution would be a one-liner (I'm looking at you, Linq).

To put it in code:

```
public OtherType ConversionA (int n) {
}

public OtherType ConversionB (int n) {
}

class MyClass {
  public MyClass (List<int> values) 
    : this (values.ConvertAllWithIndex((value, index) => 
      UseConversionA (index) ? ConversionA (value) : ConversionB (value)) {
  }

  public MyClass (List<OtherType> things) {
    ...
  }

  bool UseConversionA (int index) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I realize an easier solution for this sample code would be to perform the conversion from X to Y prior to calling MyClass and simply passing Y, but bear with me, as this is a contrived example to see if someone knows a way to replicate ConvertAll that is conditioned on the index the target element.

Also, one could create an extension to Tx to make a custom ConvertAll with index, but I'm curious if can figure out a way to make Linq (or otherwise) achieve this.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. There are too many different ways to implement what you _seem_ to be asking for, and frankly it's not entirely clear what you want as output. Did you try _anything_ at all? If you want to use LINQ, did you actually _look_ at anything in LINQ to see if it would work for you? From the question so far, it seems like you just want to use `Select()`[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx] projecting to a tuple. But that's not clear at all, and it seems like that's what you'd have done if that's actually what you wanted.

Comment: (and nothing in your narrative explains why you also have included `UseConversionA()` here. Why wouldn't you just use a `Select()` call with the conversion you want? What's the point of putting the condition _in_ the project?)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I suppose the use of Select is blatantly obvious to you, but not to me (just not familiar with all the LINQ tools; I've learned several, but tend to stick to using those I already know) and I overlooked Select.

Comment: UseConversionA() was just to make it clear (as mud, apparently) that it is some arbitrary function that decides whether to use one function or another. I can see your point though, if I have a list of values indicating which conversion to use, I could use that to control the projection.

Comment: _"use of Select is blatantly obvious to you, but not to me"_ -- your question _specifically_ mentions LINQ. For your future reference: _the_ fundamental class in LINQ is `System.Linq.Enumerable`, so anyone thinking about doing something with LINQ would start there, by reading the documentation and looking for something that suits their needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a `Select`+`ToList` combination? `Select` has an overload which gives you the index:

```
values.Select((value, index) => 
      UseConversionA(index) ? ConversionA(value) : ConversionB(value)).ToList()
```